# "If I were to go" vs "If I had gone"

Tags: subjunctive-mood

1. If I **were to go** there then I would have been injured.
2. If I **had gone** there then I would have been injured.

Is the usage of sentence 1 correct? And do both these sentences mean same?

Comment: The first sentence seems to have wonky tenses. You probably mean *If I were to go there, then I will be injured*. The difference between the sentences is then timing, with the first referring to an event in the future whilst the second refers to an event in the past.

Comment: Sentence (1) is incorrect, since "If I were" is reserved for hypothetical, future possible, and impossible, events or conditions, but not the past. "If I were a millionaire, I'd definitely live in Italy."

Comment: Also, if ... then need to be used sparingly, or they can sound clunky and unnecessary. I would suggest: "Had I gone there I would have been injured,".

Comment: Does it? I mean,does "if I were to go there" refer to timing in future?

Comment: The going could be set in the present or the future, but the result is in the future. In other words, there may be an event happening at this moment. If I were to go right now, I would be injured sometime after I arrive. In this way it works like the normal conditional: "If I go, I will be injured." But this event may not be happening until the future, and the same structure applies: "If I were to go there tomorrow, I would be injured." In other words, the "If I go" or the "If I were to go" is ambiguous as to time. What is key is the result--I will be, or I would be injured--both future.

Comment: That said, "the going" is not actually in the present either, because you have not gone. If you do go, it will be after you utter these words--in the furure. Still, the point really is what will happen as a result: If I were to do it now, or tomorrow, I would be injured.

Comment: I've got it, your suggestion would really help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. 2 is correct, though many would call for a comma after the word "there," and the word "then" could be omitted: "If I had gone there, I would have been injured." It is stating that I was not there, but if I had gone, the result would have been bad--all of this is set in the past. The subjunctive "If I were to go" states a hypothetical, presently true, but referencing the future, which makes the second half of the first sentence grammatically impossible. The subjunctive tells us that you know you are not going, or are not going to go, and the complete sentence would read: "If I were to go there, I would be injured." This could also be stated as a conditional, which allows the possibility of your going: "If I go, I will be injured."